# Form Control Checkboxes Change Height and Width when being copied/Pasted

Tags: excel, forms, checkbox

I've created some forms to fill out, then macro-enabled buttons so users will just have to click to bring up whichever form they need to use. When a button is clicked the macro copies that form from Sheet 2, then pastes it in sheet 1. These forms have Form Control checkboxes.

The first several forms have no problem being copied but the rest of the forms do. The checkboxes change in height and width when pasted to Sheet 1. I have checked their format prior to copying and they are just the same with the other forms that do not have problem so I don't know why they would cause a different result.

Comment: Please mention your Code in Question!!

Comment: You could try using ActiveX checkboxes?  These have a  .Placement property where you could set things like 'Move and Size with cells'.